# Unable to set NiceEditor content in Web Browser COntrol

Tags: c#, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am using NiceEdtor on Web Browser control. on jQuery ready() function I am trying to set content of it and in result I get following error:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'setContent'
```

Below is my given Code:

```
$(function () {
    var nicE = new nicEditors.findEditor('__edit');
    nicE.setContent("<b>Hi</b>");
});
```

Text area is defined as following:

```
<textarea name="question" rows="15" cols="130" id="__edit"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to instantiate the textarea to niceEditor control using `nicEditors.allTextAreas();` or 
`new nicEditor().panelInstance('__edit');`.

```
$(function () {

     //nicEditors.allTextAreas();  // Set globally for all textareas.
   new nicEditor().panelInstance('__edit'); // redister textarea to be a niceeditor

   ///... some code

    var nicE = new nicEditors.findEditor('__edit');
    nicE.setContent("<b>Hi</b>");
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uWfPs/)

#### [Documentation](http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=3)

Comment: I was already calling this in <head> section: *bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });*

Comment: That is the issue your `onDomLoaded` must be getting called after executing the document ready. You can check that by putting a console.log.

Comment: I guess you were wrong, anyway I removed the code from Header and moved into ready() one, now working fine. It is weird it was OK till last night. Anyway, thanks a ton bro!